# Automate left-clicks (configurable interval + number) on Debian

Tags: linux, open-source, automation, mouse

For cases where I have to left-click many times on the same spot, I would like to have a tool that relieves me from having to do it manually.

Setting it up should be easy, ideally self-explanatory (without having to read the man page in case I didn’t use it for a few months). I will use it rarely, and always for different cases, so I will configure it on the fly for each case. It should be easier/faster to set it up than to click 100 times manually, otherwise I would probably not bother to use it.

#### Requirements

- It must be FLOSS.
- It must work on Debian (GNU/Linux).
- It must be available from [Debian’s package directories](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages).

#### Desired workflow

1. Open the tool.
2. Set interval (e.g., every 2 seconds) and number (e.g., 100 clicks).
3. Move the mouse to the location.
4. Press a key combination to start the left-clicking.

#### Bonus

- A GUI.
- To prevent clicking the wrong spots (when accidentally moving the mouse), it would be great if the mouse cursor gets locked (until it finished or until I press a key combination to pause/stop it) or the script pauses as soon as I move the mouse.
- Allow setting a random interval (e.g., anything between 1 and 3 seconds per click).

Answer (score 1):

[Sikuli X](http://sikulix.com/) could be the answer to your needs. It is a test framework based on OpenCV that uses image recognition to determine the actions to take.  Scripts can be run in Python, Ruby, JavaScript, RobotFramework.

- FLOSS - **Yes**
- Debian - **Fully Cross Platform**
- In package directory **Not currently** - *Single .jar on launchpad*
- GUI - **Yes**
- Cursor Locked - **No** *but since the screen is searched each time the mouse will go back to where it is needed*
- Any interval - **Yes**

The workflow, *using the default python scripting*:

1. Open the GUI
2. Click on the button for click on screen
3. Select the item on the screen that you need to click on
4. Make the above into a loop with `for x in range(100):`
5. Edit the script to add a `sleep` after each click
6. *Optionally save the script for re-use*
7. Run the script

*You do need to ensure that the image that you are looking for is on the main monitor of the system.*

Silly Example:
[image]